# Continuity of a function defined by inequality relation with two function

Tags: limits, inequality, continuity

$\displaystyle\int_{x^2}^x \sqrt \frac{1-t}{t}\,\mathrm dt \lt G(x) \lt 2\!\cdot\!\sqrt x $

where $x$ belongs to interval $(0,1)$.

Is it always a continuous function or it is possible to have such a function, which is not continuous?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The leftmost expression is not well-defined. If $x \in (0,1)$, then you are integrating for $t$ in some subset of $(0,1)$, and then $t-1 < 0$. For instance, if $x=1/2$, then you have
$$
\int_{1/4}^{1/2} \sqrt{ \frac{t-1}{t} } dt
$$
but $t-1 \in (-3/4,-1/2)$.

Comment: There does not exists functions $f$ and $h$ such that if $g$ satisfies $f(x) < g(x) < h(x)$ for every $x$, then $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @PrincessEev I have made a mistake in question. Now, It is rectified. Thanks to point out the error.